# Updating aliases with sequalize db

Tags: node.js, database, server

In my data model, I have an instance: db.items , which has relation "hasMany" with db.images, db.services. So one item can have many images and many services.

I would like to update my instance calling the following:

```
  let res = await db.items
      .upsert(
        {
          id: req.body.id,
          type: req.body.type,
          name: req.body.name,
          images: req.body.images,
          services: req.body.services
        },
        {
          include: [
            {
              model: db.images,
              as: "images"
            },
            {
              model: db.services,
              as: "services"
            }
          ]
        }
      );
```

The problem is that all the aliases are not updated, but the name and type of the item updated. What could be the problem? Include perfectly works with db.create() call, but with upsert - maybe there is a different way of doing things?

Comment: I think you're not using upsert as it's supposed to, please check this link https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/ for further mongodb update info.

Comment: I'm targeting MySQL db in my case